# How to hide browser scroll bar for specific page

Tags: html, css, vue.js

How do I get browser scrollbar to be hidden on only one page, of many, on a website. The only way I can get the browser scrollbar to hide at all is with

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

However this hides the scrollbar for the entire site.

Comment: maybe give the body tags different IDs?

Comment: Are you able to target a class in the body tag that is specific to that page, eg are you using wordpress?

Comment: @CarolMcKay I am not using WordPress. I am using laravel/vuejs.

Comment: When you say hide, do you want the page to be scrollable but the bar itself should be hidden? Or do you want to stop scroll behavior?

Answer (score -1):

Add overflow: hidden; to hide both the horizontal and vertical scrollbar.

```
*body {
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide scrollbars */
}*
```